# "Cannot find symbol variable" compilation error for inner class

Tags: java, android

I'm a newcomer to Java and this is probably a basic question, but after looking at some references on inner classes I can't figure out why this android code produces a compilation error of "cannot find symbol variable ButtonListener" in the OnCreate method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private class ButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("TAG", "test");
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButtonListener = new ButtonListener();
        registerReceiver(ButtonListener, new IntentFilter("12345"));
    }
```

Comment: ButtonListener = new ButtonListener();  < this seems to be missing a variable name for the listener, which might be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to give your variable a name! Try

```
ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
registerReceiver(listener, new IntentFilter("12345"));
```

Both lines had an error. The first line specified the class of the variable, but not its name (and that's what the compiler burped about). The second line needed you to pass a variable for the first argument, and you specified the name of the class instead of the name of the variable (an understandable mistake, since it didn't have a name!).

Comment: DOh, didn't have the coffee this morning

Comment: @MrH happens to us all! :)

Comment: @MrH be glad you didn't enter it all onto punch cards and then have to correct and punch them all again...